# Excel VBA UserForm 'OK'

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how to make a userform function in the same way as the Message Box 'ok' button? I'll explain.

I'm detecting errors in a column in a spreadsheet. When an error is found, a message box pops up as follows:

MsgBox "Please enter valid data"

When I select "OK" it goes to the next error in the column. This is great, except of course a message box is modal, which freezes the application. I want the user to be able to edit the data and then move to the next error. So, I designed a userform, which can be non-modal. Great, except I want the macro to advance to the next error. It will do that IF the user corrects the error. If they do not, it just stays at that error cell.

I know WHY this happens. My userform 'Next' button just calls the macro which finds the first error. But what I want to know is if there is a way around this.

Error checking starts at row 19 because that is where user input data starts.

I'm including a link to the spreadsheet here. Module 1 'NextValidationError' works great and proceeds to the next error. Module 14 just hangs at the error until it is resolved. I'd like it to be able to skip.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yqko5kj19pnauc9/Transparency%20Data%20Input%20Sheet%20for%20Indirect%20Spend%20V7%2009212016%20v2%200.xlsm?dl=0

Can anyone give me advice on how to make module 14 proceed as module 1?

Comment: Store the row number `r` of the last error in a Global variable, and when the user clicks "Next" start your checking on the next row.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the advice. Could you possibly demonstrate or elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim r_start As Long

Sub CheckNames()
    Dim r As Long
    'Dim emptyRow As Boolean

     If r_start = 0 Then r_start = 19

     With ActiveSheet
        For r = r_start To 5000
            'Checks entire row for data. User may skip rows when entering data.
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, 33))) > 0 Then
                If ((.Cells(r, 2) = "") <> (.Cells(r, 3) = "")) Or _
                   ((.Cells(r, 2) = "") = (.Cells(r, 4) = "")) Then

                    MsgBox "Please fill in First and Last Name or HCO in Row " & r & "."

                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Unless I'm mis-reading your code you can combine your two checks with `Or`.

You will need some method to reset `r_start` when the user is done checking (if the form stays open after that).

EDIT: here's a very basic example.
UserForm1 has two buttons - "Next" and "Close"

Code for "next" is just:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ShowErrors
End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```
Dim r_start As Long

'this kicks off the checking process
Sub StartChecking()
    r_start = 0
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
    ShowErrors
End Sub

'a simple example validation...
Sub ShowErrors()

    Dim c As Range, r As Long

    If r_start = 0 Then r_start = 9

    For r = r_start To 200
        With ActiveSheet.Rows(r)
            If Not IsNumeric(.Cells(1).Value) Then
                UserForm1.lblMsg.Caption = "Cell " & .Cells(1).Address() & " is not numeric!"
                r_start = r + 1
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    Next r

    r_start = 0

    UserForm1.lblMsg.Caption = "No more errors"

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, when I replace MsgBox with UserForm2.show, it does not advance. Actually, it didn't in my original code, either :( The two buttons in my UserForm2 are Close, which unloads the form and Next which calls CheckNames. Do you know if I should change either button? Also, r_start isn't incremented or called at all throughout this function, does that matter? I'm sorry if I'm being dense here. I'm sure this is clear to you. You ARE right in that I could combine the two checks with Or. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Not knowing anything about how your userform is structured, it's difficult to  figure out exactly what you're doing...  What is triggering the beginning of the process?

Comment: Sure, the process is triggered by the user. Once all data is entered, user selects button to check data. This is only one of many checks, but it is the only one I can't get to work.

Code for userform2 is as follows, where CommandButton1 is titled 'Close' and exits the process and CommandButton2 is titled 'Next' and calls CheckNames. Does that make sense at all?

Option Explicit


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveSheet.Range("A18").Select
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Call CheckNames
End Sub

Comment: @MatthewIngle - it's best to edit your own question if you have a follow-up question about an answer, rather than editing the answer...  At this point it might be easier to share the workbook (or some cleaned-up version of it) if you're able to do that.

Comment: @MatthewIngle - well that's a lot of code...  As it stands it very difficult to see how the flow works, since each validation is a separate sub *and* a separate form.  I think it would benefit from a re-write: create a single procedure which validates the whole row, and then have your form show all of the errors on that row (use a label or a Multi-line text box).  You only need one generic form: update the caption and/or a label dynamically if you need to change what the user sees at any given point.

Comment: I think you're right Tim. I know it's waaay too much code and could probably be simplified. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: No problem: I think it's difficult to come up with a really generic approach, since you have a few different types of potential errors, some dependent fields ,etc etc.